# Predicting the area of each crop in the next season in the farm based on historic data

Tags: time-series, distributions

I have a farm with 10 years data about the area and type of crops which planted. The whole area of the farm is  220 hec and 4 different types of crops (Rice, Maize, Wheat and pasture (and uncultivated area)) are normally  planting in this farm.  . I know the area of each crop in the last 10 years. How can I predict the area of each crop in the next season?